# jQuery image replacement with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm really new to all this coding things etc. (1 month :P) and actually i try some things with jQuery.
I used the search function but actually it's quite hard for me to understand everything :P

My goal is:
When i hover over an image another image which sits on top of it slides up and another slides down.

They're all images - i don't want to publish the Website and only want to use it on my Computer for testing ^^
Also the picture on the top should be hidden at first. (I know how to do it but i actually don't know if it will be shown when using slideDown)

HTML:

```
<div class="newschange">
<div class="News wow fadeInDown animated"><img src="images/News.png" /></div>
<div class="newstext wow fadeInUp animated"><img src="images/newstext.png" /></div>
<div class="newshover"><img src="images/alt/newstext.png" /></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery Script: (it's actually in the header of the HTML)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('.News').mouseover(function (){
   $(.'newstext').slideUp(300);
   $(.'newshover').delay(400),slideDown(300);
   });
   })
    </script>
```

CSS (i don't know if this is necesarry for this :P)

```
.newshover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 802px;
  top: 455px;
  width: 359px;
  height: 35px; 
}
.newstext {
  position: absolute;
  left: 781px;
  top: 456px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 32px; 
}
.News {
  position: absolute;
  left: 377px;
  top: 276px;
  width: 854px;
  height: 318px;
  }
```

The problem is just that nothing happens when i hover over it :)
Here is a Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzyFH.png
The 1. image is the whole thing with at the top "News" the image and the rounded rectangle.
NEWS SECTION! is the one i want to show AFTER i hover over the first image.
The red Text behind it is the one i want to hide when i hover over the first image. :)

//solved Code

```
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".News").on('mouseenter',function () {
        $(".newshover").delay(600).slideToggle(500);
        $(".newstext").slideToggle(500);
    });  
    $(".News").on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(".newshover").slideToggle(500);
        $(".newstext").delay(600).slideToggle(500);
    })
});
    </script>


    <script>
    $(function(){
$(".newshover").hide(0);
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: If your javascript is in the header, you'll need to wrap it in a document ready since the HTML elements won't exist yet. `$(function() { //your code; });`

Comment: Thanks :) I already heard about it but totally forget about it x.x Probably i'm trying to learn to much things at the same time :O

Comment: You have a few issues in your jQuery. Your selectors for `newstext` and `newshover` have the period on the outside of the quotation marks, they need to be on the inside like they are for the `News` selector. Also, you're missing a semicolon at the end of your document ready function.

Comment: Here is an update jsfiddle with a few bugs I found. http://jsfiddle.net/c1nm3z1b/

Comment: How did you fix it exactly @PixelStudio?

Comment: It's not working now i just pasted the code by Neil Master into mine. Actually i'm uploading a Screenshot because the solution of you isn't exactly what i want ^^ But i have slow internet so it actually takes some time :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your question this piece of code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/5naaq121/

HTML:

```
<div class="newschange">
<div class="News"><img src="http://maalaeasurfresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/beach_cy.jpg" /></div>
<div class="newstext"><img src="http://www.honduras.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/white-sandy-beach2-300x200.jpg" /></div>
<div class="newshover"><img src="http://www.lakecountyparks.com/_images/whihala_beach/wb_beach.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.newschange').mouseenter(function (){
       $('.newshover').slideUp(300);
       $('.newstext').delay(400).slideUp(300);
   })
});
```

CSS:

```
.newschange {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;  
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.newshover {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;    
}
.newstext {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
.News {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks :) After some trying your code with mouseenter and mouseleave worked for me - but i changed it a little bit ;) (Final-Code at Startpost)